# remove even length

Tags: java

Write a method removeEvenLength that takes an ArrayList of Strings as a parameter and that removes all of the strings of even length from the list.

```
public void removeEvenLength(ArrayList <String> stringList){
    for(int i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
        String word=stringList.get(i);
        if(word.length()%2==0){//even
            stringList.remove(word);//if it is even,test from the first word  then continue looping


        }


    }
}
```

When i tried to pass in ["This", "is", "a", "test"],it should return me a.But instead it is giving me is,a.What's wrong with it?

Comment: IMO this is a valid question. It is a common newbie error. I don't see the need for downvote.

Comment: Sorry.Actually i repeated my java module so i am very weak in my concepts so i may tend to ask simpler questions.

Comment: You should note that this isn't necessarily a bad pattern for working with lists, but once you start working with foreach loops this breaks down.

Comment: I just reacted to the downvotes on your question. You showed effort and stumbled on a problem, I cannot understand where the downvotes come from.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: you are removing the current item from the list during iteration. Think about what effect this might have on the iteration that follows.

Comment: So if i remove it,i should i=i+1?

Comment: @user2179615: I leave it to you to figure out what needs to happen.

Comment: I manage to get the answer with i=i-1.but I dont understand it.Since i deduct one value,shouldn't i add back instead of minus?

Comment: think about the size of the list after you remove

Answer (score 1):

Use an Iterator when removing an item from a list while looping over it. It will handle this problem for you.

```
public void removeEvenLength( List<String> stringList ) {
    Iterator<String> iterator = stringList.iterator();
    while( iterator.hasNext() ) {
        final String word = iterator.next();
        if( word.length() % 2 == 0 ) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

A better approach would be to create a new list with all the values which have odd lengths. This way you are not modifying the original list. Generally, the more functions do not have side effects, the better they will be.

```
public List<String> removeEvenLength( List<String> stringList ) {
    List<String> oddList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for( String word : stringList ) {
        if( word.length % 2 == 1 ) {
            oddList.add( word );
        }
    }
    return oddList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These answers all seem so complex...

Whenever you need to modify the number of elements in a list, in order to avoid affecting the indices of elements that are not yet tested, you should traverse the list in reverse.

```
    public static void removeEvenLength(ArrayList<String> arr){
        for(int i=arr.size()-1; i>=0; i--)
            if(arr.get(i).length() % 2 == 0)
                arr.remove(i);
    }
```

No need to create a copy of a list, or alter the for loop counter in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the below? It works for me

```
import java.util.*;

class Fun
{
    public static void removeEvenLength(ArrayList <String> stringList){
        for(int i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
            String word=stringList.get(i);
            if(word.length()%2==0){//even
                stringList.remove(word);//if it is
                i = i-1;
                continue;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
            String word=stringList.get(i);
            System.out.println(word);
        }
    }

public static void main(String []args)
{
    ArrayList <String> stringList = new ArrayList <String>();
    stringList.add("this");
    stringList.add("is");
    stringList.add("a");
    stringList.add("test");
    removeEvenLength(stringList);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 you can use removeIf(predicate) to remove an element from a Collection without the need of manually create an Iterator:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("1234","wsxw","qaz","qwertyui","q","qwe","qwerty","qwqw"));
set.removeIf(p -> p.length() %2 == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way of doing this:)

```
public static void removeEvenLength(ArrayList<String> l){

    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String word : l){

        if(word.length()%2==0){temp.add(word);}

    }

    l.removeAll(temp);
    


}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void removeEvenLength(ArrayList <String> stringList){
        for(int i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
            String word=stringList.get(i);
            System.out.println(word+" "+word.length()+" "+word.length()%2);
            if(word.length()%2==0){//even
                System.out.println("Rmoving "+word);
                stringList.remove(word);
                removeEvenLength(stringList);//Recursive call
            }
        }
    }
```

Use recursive call to function.

Comment: why do you need recursion?

Comment: Offcourse there are other ways also.For me, this one is simpler.

Comment: Why are you looping over the list if you are using recursion? This example needs some work. The "recursive" aspect is totally useless in this example.